# Persistent environmental issues in Python - installed Python packages fail to load

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, spacy

I am a novice Python user trying to use Python packages from scripts and Jupyter Notebook (installed using Anaconda). For some reason the import statements always fail. However they seem to work fine when used from the interactive terminal.

Here is a screenshot illustrating my issue. What am I missing here? Any help from Python users out there will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I would always recommend using the command line to install modules.
just as important, never attach screenshots again, just text, if you want to be helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacy is lowercase for import and installation.

```
import spacy
```

But yeah, if you have access to the command line that’s the way to go. You can spend some time with the conda docs, they’re well-written.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. It worked with a lower case s - I feel silly but really appreciate the help. I would have given you a few more upvote if Stackoverflow allowed it :)